# How to create shared elements in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I am beginner for WebStorm.

I am going to create a web application. If I am going to add header, footer, navigation bar for each page, how do I do it in WebStorm so I don't have to create these for every page?

Comment: This would be entirely dependent on what framework / application stack you are using and not Webstorm itself.

Comment: So let's say if I use PHP, then I have to choose PHP storm as my IDE? then what is purpose to use Webstorm, front end design only?

Comment: You can use [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) or some another templating engine for that -- it all depends on your framework/stack that you are using. If you want to use PHP .. then you will have to use PhpStorm instead of WebStorm (PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + Databases).